# avg_over_time of a max

Tags: promql, metricsql

I have a gauge metric `badness` which goes up when my service is performing poorly. There is one gauge per instance of the service and I have many instances.

I can take a max over all instances so that I can see how bad the worst instance is:

```
max(badness)
```

This graph is noisy because the identity of the worst instance, and how bad it is, changes frequently. I would like to smooth it out by applying a moving average. However, this doesn't work (I get a PromQL syntax error):

```
avg_over_time(max(badness)[1m])
```

How can I apply `avg_over_time()` to a timeseries that has already been aggregated with the `max()` operator?

My backend is VictoriaMetrics so I can use either MetricsQL or pure PromQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `avg_over_time(max(process_resident_memory_bytes)[5m])` query works without issues in VictoriaMetrics. It may fail if you use [promxy](https://github.com/jacksontj/promxy) in front of VictoriaMetrics, since `promxy` doesn't support [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) - see [this issue](https://github.com/jacksontj/promxy/issues/253) for details.

The query can be fixed, so it may work in Prometheus and promxy - just add a colon after `5m` in square brackets:

```
avg_over_time(max(process_resident_memory_bytes)[5m:])
```

This is named [subquery](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/) in Prometheus world. See mode details about subquery specifics in VictoriaMetrics and Prometheus in [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3)